# ImageGrid component or something like that

Tags: c#, components

I'm writing a Client for an online game in C#.The client(Game) has inventory:

[alt text http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/5606/inventoryplain.jpg](http://img232.imageshack.us/img232/5606/inventoryplain.jpg)

The 42 blocks in left and the 12 blocks in right must contain images of the "virtual items" that the "virtual character" contains.

I added 54 panels(42 left+12 right) on top of every single block with the idea to use the BackGroundImage property to add the image at a specific block.

Most things in that game are server sided so I receive the item position and the item via TCP Client.

The problem is that if I receive position "13" and assign that value to a integer variable named "position", I can't call

"panel+ position + .BackGroundImage = image

I either have to find a way to do this or remove all panels and use one component,but I would still have that problem.

Any help on this issue will be appreciated!
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all the panels to an array.

Eg:

```
Panel[] panels = { panel0, panel1, ... }
```